# How to get facebook user information using nodejs (oauth)

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am trying to fetch facebook user information using node-oauth but its giving missing page error on the browser when i am trying to perform oauth

**Code**
**oauth2.getAuthorize call:**

```
app.get("/facebook/auth", (req, res) => {
  var redirect_uri = "https://localhost:3000/facebook/callback"
  var params = {
    redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
    scope: "user_about_me,publish_actions",
  };
  res.redirect(oauth2.getAuthorizeUrl(params));
});
```

**Call to read code and access_token in oauth-redirected page**

```
app.get("/facebook/callback", function (req, res) {
  if (req.error_reason) {
    res.send(req.error_reason);
  }
  if (req.query.code) {
    var loginCode = req.query.code;
    var redirect_uri = "https://localhost:3000/facebook/callback";
    oauth2.getOAuthAccessToken(
      loginCode,
      { grant_type: "authorization_code", redirect_uri: redirect_uri },
      function (err, accessToken, refreshToken, params) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          res.send(err);
        }
        var access_token = accessToken;
        var expires = params.expires;
        req.session.access_token = access_token;
        req.session.expires = expires;
      }
    );
  }
});
```

**Error page:**
[image]

Comment: The permissions `user_about_me` and `publish_actions` are both not available any more in current API versions.

Comment: Thank you, Could you please suggest me any valid scopes or document link for this

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference